# Reverse comma separated column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following column which contains values separated by comma. How do I convert it to a result set which gives following out put in SQL Server?

```
DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE
(COLUMN1  NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TBL 
SELECT 'AUD,BRL,GBP,CAD,CLP'

SELECT COLUMN1 FROM @TBL

COLUMN1
-------
AUD,BRL,GBP,CAD,CLP
```

Result I wanted:

```
COLUMN1
-------
AUD
BRL
GBP
CAD
CLP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
 SELECT Split.T.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS column1  
 FROM  (SELECT  CAST ('<M>' + 
 REPLACE(column1, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
 FROM  @TBL) AS T CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(T);
```

Comment: Can you please help me to find a reference to Split.T.value function?

Comment: I used XML nodes() method in the query. You can find the book online reference at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, that's a beginners mistake. Redesign your database so that you have each of these entries in a separate table and you aren't using 'repeating groups' any more. Or at least if you're going to do anything significant with your database you need to.

```
create table Table1(
  Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) not null -- PK
)

create table Table2
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) not null, -- PK
    Table1Id int not null, -- FK to Table1
    Column1 varchar(50) not null
)

select *
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.Table1Id = t1.Id
order by t1.Id, t2.Column1
```

Comment: Good advice but it does not answer the question.  Minus 1.

Comment: And +1. SOmeone here may not like it, but it IS a beginner mistake. THere is this thing called the relational theorem by cobbs and obviously many people these days think "learning how to use a tool properly" is crap. Relational databases are build around a concept. Live with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE
(COLUMN1  NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TBL 
SELECT 'AUD,BRL,GBP,CAD,CLP'


 SELECT SUBSTRING(',' + COLUMN1 + ',', Number + 1,
CHARINDEX(',', ',' + COLUMN1 + ',', Number + 1) - Number -1)AS CaseID
FROM master..spt_values
cross join @TBL t
where type = 'P'
and Number <= LEN(',' + COLUMN1 + ',') - 1
AND SUBSTRING(',' + COLUMN1 + ',', Number, 1) = ','
```